macOS Sonoma usb drive stuck on DiskMountApproval in diskutil
I have a USB drive which is not showing up on finder or disk utility (in fact disk utility stuck on loading when inserted)
running diskutil activity shows this log:
***DiskPeek ('disk4s1') Time=20240604-17:27:19.2469
***DiskAppeared ('disk4s1', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = 'exfat', DAVolumeName = 'SD 128GB') Time=20240604-17:27:19.2539
***DiskMountApproval ('disk4s1', DAVolumePath = '<null>', DAVolumeKind = 'exfat', DAVolumeName = 'SD 128GB') Comment=Approving Time=20240604-17:27:19.2553

Nothing else appears after DiskMountApproval. Why is this happening. I tried on a different Mac with same results. How can I get this to work without erasing anything on disk?
Update
Tried diskutil list but this command hangs indefinitely when the usb stick is inserted.

Does it work on a Windows PC? exFat will be supported there also. Please add the output from diskutil list. Even if the volume doesn't mount, the USB device should show up.

@AndyGriffiths diskutil list hangs indefinitely when usb is inserted. Nothing shows up.

Does anything show up in Console.app near this activity log?
